# Excel VBA Use selected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA newbie here. I just need a macro that will refresh the queries I have on a single sheet I'm viewing. I already have the refresh macro but I always have to specify the sheet name that I want to refresh. Is it possible to have the macro run on whatever sheet I'm viewing? Here's the macro in it's current state:

```
Sub Refresh_Query()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [`ActiveSheet.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174742%28v=office.11%29.aspx), such as:

```
Sub Refresh_Query()
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Sub Refresh_Query()
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: -1 ActiveSheet has no QueryTable property. It does have a QueryTables property, so ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1) would work.

Comment: Thanks, @Doug. Did not know that (obviously).

Comment: +1 for this edited answer. The `Select` in the initial question and accepted answer are redundant

Answer (score 1):

The OP is ambiguous: text asks to refresh all query tables on the active sheet, but sample code only refreshes the one query table that contains cell `B3`

To refresh only one query table use

```
Sub RefreshOneQuery()
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    On Error Resume Next  ' in case there is no qt containing cell B6
    Set qt = Range("B6").QueryTable
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not qt Is Nothing Then
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

To refresh all query tables on the sheet use

```
Sub RefreshAllQueries()
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next
End Sub
```